# Fibonacci Pisano: how to improve (Python3)

Tags: python, fibonacci

I was trying to output F(n) mod m to find the remainder of Fibonacci number, where F(n) could be a very big number:

```
# Uses python3
n, m =  [int(x) for x in input().split()]

def fib(n):
    a = [0, 1]
    if (n <=1):
        return n
    else:
        for i in range(1, n):
            a.append((a[-1] + a[-2])%m)
        return a[i+1]
print (fib(n))
```

As I typed in `239 1000`, it returns `161` as the remainder, which is correct. But with bigger inputs eg. `2816213588 239`, it seems to exceed time limits, what can I do to improve the code? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you don't need to store every number in a list. You only need the preceding two numbers so you can calculate the next.

Comment: Your question should be asked here - https://codereview.stackexchange.com/